# CCXT : Is there an easy way to fetch only "free" assets from an exchange?

Tags: python, ccxt

Is there a simple way to receive only "free" assets information from an exchange, i.e. assets of which I have a balance and this balance is available (free) to be used in trades ?

Right now I am fetching all assets with fetch_balance(), remove most of the information with balanceJSON.pop() and filter out all assets with zero quantity leaving me just with the free asset balances.

```
balanceJSON = await ccxt.fetch_balance()
balanceJSON.pop('free')
balanceJSON.pop('info')
balanceJSON.pop('total')
balanceJSON.pop('used')
if(exchange != 'BYBIT'):
     balanceJSON.pop('timestamp')
     balanceJSON.pop('datetime')
balanceDict = appHelper.removeZeroValues(balanceJSON)

#appHelper
def removeZeroValues(val):
     try:
         nonzerolist = {}
         for key, value in val.items():
             if not value['total'] < 0.01 :
                 nonzerolist[key] = value
     except Exception as e:
         print('removeZeroValues Exception occured with - {}'.format(e))
     finally:
         return nonzerolist
```

This is a lengthy process and I would prefer to find a faster way which I could not find in CCXT.
Thanks !